# Avoid mail notification on update drive permission

Tags: google-drive-api

Every change in a Drive Permission will send a notification mail. Is there any way to avoid this?

Many thanks in advance,
Ridgh

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you insert a new permission with the Drive API, you can set the `sendNotificationEmails` optional parameter to false to avoid sending that email:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works in Java:

```
service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).setSendNotificationEmails(false).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for PHP language:

```
$this->service->permissions->create($folder->id, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id', 'sendNotificationEmail' => false));
```

Answer (score 1):

on c# (api v3), you have to set SendNotificationEmail to false after you create request as in;

```
var req = _driveService.Permissions.Create(
                        new Permission
                        {
                            Role = "reader",
                            Type = "user",
                            EmailAddress = readerEmail
                        }, document.DocumentId);
                    req.SendNotificationEmail = false;
                    req.Execute();
```