# google drive disable permission change notification email

Tags: google-drive-api

i want to disable the notification email in my C# application if permissions get changed. i found a property of service.permissions.insert called SendNotificationEmails but i dont know how to use it.
i tried [Avoid mail notification on update drive permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472223/avoid-mail-notification-on-update-drive-permission)

my code:
return service.Permissions.Insert(newPermission,fileId).SendNotificationEmails(Boolean.TrueString).execute();

but i get an error: "non-invocable member 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.PermissionsResource.InsertRequest.SendNotificationEmails' cannot be used like a method"

thanks!
markus

Answer (score 10):

`SendNotificationEmails` is a field, not a method. Use the following instead:

```
InsertRequest req = service.Permissions.Insert(newPermission, fileId);
req.SendNotificationEmails = true;
req.Fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to go the length of Burcu's answer.

Just change your code to

```
return service.Permissions.Insert(newPermission,fileId).setSendNotificationEmails(false).execute();
```

That'll do the job just as good and much shorter.